# É possível forçar html5 vídeo a tocar videos com outras extensões, como se fosse vídeo normal?

Tags: vídeo, html5-video

Tenho esse cliente, que por razões que só ele poderia entender, gravou milhares de vídeos e salvou eles com extensões estranhas, terminando em `.ts`, `.mp3`, `.mp4`, `.mpg`, `.blib`, `.reuniao`, `.banco`, `.manut`, etc...

Sendo que todos na verdade são arquivos de vídeo `.mpg`.
NOVAMENTE, Por razões que só ele pode entender não posso modificar nada nos arquivos.

Agora ele precisa disponibilizar tudo no site dele como vide-o aulas... naturalmente tentei usar o básico em HTML5:

```
<video id="video1" src="https://www.someSite.com/someVideo.blib" >
</video>
```

Mas claro que não tocou, mesmo aquele arquivo sendo `.mpg` normal... Detalhe: se troco a extensão dos arquivos `.blib` para `.mpg`, os videos rodam!

Tentei configurar o .htaccess no servidor para informar ao navegador o formato de vídeo mas não fui muito feliz...

```
#Vídeo
AddType video/mp4 .mp4 .m4v
AddType video/mpg .mpg
AddType video/ts .ts
AddType video/blib .blib
AddType video/reuniao .reuniao
AddType video/banco .banco
AddType video/manut .manut
```

Agora fica minha pergunta..
Como posso fazer o html5-vídeo tocar o arquivo de vídeo com extensões diferentes?

Comment: O que o @LucasBarroso respondeu tem sentido, veja: https://media.giphy.com/media/3ohze06NBH8AQbVvS8/giphy.gif

Comment: MUITO provavelmente o seu problema sejam os codecs dos videos

Comment: Caso a edição tenha alterado o **sentido da pergunta**, podes reverter para o estado anterior...
Ao meu ver a edição melhorou o entendimento... mas, fica a seu critério :)

Comment: Explique o que queria saber então, no meu entendimento se tratava justamente da extensão do arquivo :) Se não for isso, sua pergunta pode ser fechada como não clara...

Comment: `Agora ele precisa disponibilizar tudo no site dele como vide-o aulas` eis o motivo de ele ter feito o que fez. Trata-se de um tiozão. E o princípio da incerteza de Murphy diz que quanto mais tiozão for o usuário, mais coisa errada ele vai fazer quando tiver acesso a um computador.

Comment: Ola @Renan, gosto de filosofia!  Obrigado pelo seu input. MAS a questão que fica  me parece mais simples. O cliente  quer?  **(SIM)**  ... Ele vai pagar por isso? **(SIM)** Tem gente que consegue fazer? **(SIM)**  O cliente vai usar la .. do jeito dele? **(SIM)** eu vou ter que usar ISSO **(nao, usa quem quer)** podemos insistir pra ele usar como achamos o **certo** ??  **(nao sei, cada um perde seu tempo como quiser)** Vale a pena convencer o cliente? **(sei la...  ele vai usar isso la dentro do quarto dele, entre 4 paredes, com o aluno dele)**  então,  ta resolvido.  Não é minha grana, logo.

Answer (score 1):

Entendi seu caso com as extensões diferentonas, talvez a tag video cause alguns problemas para você. Recentemente eu trabalhei em um projeto com vídeos e tive que tratar os formatos usando FFMPEG para exportar em MP4 e toquei eles usando o MediaElement http://www.mediaelementjs.com/

Esse player é bem bacana e usa a tag video como base, mas mantém o mesmo estilo/tema (bonitão) em todos os navegadores, além de dar suporte para formatos como flv e até streaming.

Eu acabei de fazer um teste e esse player funcionou para um arquivo.mp4 renomeado para arquivo.banco, mas na tag video base para montar o player eu mantive o atributo type="video/mp4"

Montei um exemplo com tudo que você precisa para fazer funcionar

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mediaelement/build/mediaelementplayer.css">
<script src="mediaelement/build/mediaelement-and-player.js"></script>
<script src="mediaelement/build/lang/pt-br.js"></script>

<video class="player" controls preload="false" width="640" height="360" controlsList="nodownload">
    <source src="videos/arquivo.banco" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Para ativar o plugin:

```
mejs.i18n.language('pt-BR'); //Traduz o player

$('video.player').mediaelementplayer({
    pluginPath: "mediaelement/build/",
    stretching: 'responsive'
});
```

Comment: Ola Evandro, obrigado pela resposta, vou estudar esse player ja, inclusive to procurando um exemplo pra tocar streaming (de uma fonte que fornece videos em  **.TS**).. mas ta dificil...  se  nao for muito encomodo.. poderia colocar um codigo no fidle?  sou novata e estou estudando...  agradeceria a ajuda...

Comment: por exemplo, como tocar o streaming **"http://dveo.com/downloads/TS-sample-files/San_Diego_Clip.ts"**  ???   __1) Hoje se coloco essa URL no navegador... ele pede pra salvar..   __2) se coloco no exemplo que você deu.. ele nao faz nada....

Comment: @CamilaYamamoto criei um Fiddle com o mesmo código que usei na resposta, no exemplo tive que usar um vídeo público com a extensão .mp4,  mas já testei rodando local e funciona para seu caso. Veja exemplo https://jsfiddle.net/o28bojLc/

Comment: olha acho que estou errando algo pois, no exemplo com o video publico "dveo.com/downloads/TS-sample-files/San_Diego_Clip.ts"   la da http://diveo.com, nao vai...     e JUSTAMENTE esse tipo de extenssao... eh meu problema atual...  por favor.. pode me dar uma luz?   tem como criar o **.M3U**   ou **.M3U8** local, "apontando" para aquele arquivo remoto do exemplo publico???   agradeco a ajuda!!!

Comment: Na pergunta original você não comenta nada sobre streaming... Eu fiz o teste usando esse player com um arquivo local mp4 renomeado com extensão diferente, e funcionou, isso pra mim era o que você estava precisando. Ví que você já criou outra pergunta sobre esse caso do M3U, talvez tenha confundido os assuntos, mas aqui a solução já foi dada no exemplo que citei acima

Comment: sim.. voc eesta coretto SOBRE A PERGUNTA, depois completei em um comentario "Ola Evandro, obrigado pela resposta, vou estudar esse player ja, inclusive to procurando um exemplo pra tocar streaming (de uma fonte que fornece videos em .TS).. mas ta dificil... se nao for muito encomodo.. poderia colocar um codigo no fidle? sou novata e estou estudando... agradeceria a ajuda.""   certo???

Comment: e depois aind acoloquie um exemplo..   TAMBEM NOS COMENTARIOS.... mas achoque isso nao interessa mais.. so causou dor e sofrimento. 

talvez eu abra outro post.

Comment: Várias pessoas aqui tentaram te ajudar! Eu postei uma solução para o que entendi da sua pergunta, e respondi nos comentários o que me pediu. Outros pediram que você detalhasse mais seu problema. Você respondeu todos com grosseria. Usou caixa alta e sarcasmo. Sua postura não combina com essa comunidade. 

Ao ler isso talvez você responda com mais grosseria ou até me avalie negativamente... Não voltarei nesse post para dar continuidade nesse assunto, mas lamento por você e pelos colegas que tentaram te ajudar.

Menos ódio por favor.

Answer (score -1):

Se entendi bem, você quer que o navegador toque um vídeo.ts em vídeo.mp4, é isso?
Não roda. Se tá na construção do site que é pra puxar um arquivo vídeo.ts, ele vai buscar, se não encontrar ele vai retornar null..

Comment: BOM...  repetindo..   """""""""""""EH TUDO .MPG """""""""""""".....   o cliente que nao sei por que .. gravou com outros nomes.... POREM em formato .mpg.......................  pra se ter uma ideia tem ate .mp3 MAS TAMBEM SAO  arquivos de video......

Comment: Desculpa, não posso te ajudar, ta muito confuso pra mim isso tudo... De repente vc poderia colocar uma imagem, um exemplo ou algo do tipo.

Comment: no tilulo do post.. eu coloque..   ARQUIVO COM NOME ERRADO... porem de .video .mpg

Comment: É... Pelo que eu entendi kkkk não dá não... Mas com uma imagem de exemplo sairia mais fácil.

Comment: imagem?   mas e meu problema eh com video... ??!  Por favor como eu posso te dar uma imagem de exemplo de um video?

Comment: Quando o @SandsonCosta pediu uma imagem, acredito que seja uma imagem de exemplo do que você quer fazer :) Você que entendeu errado

Answer (score -1):

Pelo que entendi, seu problema é na extensão do vídeo, correto?
Eu testei usando o Chrome e funcionou tranquilo com a extensão diferente (.blib, .banco, etc)

Seja qual for o seu problema, não custa você tentar usar algum player de vídeo ao invés de usar HTML5 direto...

Eu recomendo tentar o [jwplayer](https://www.jwplayer.com/), ou algumas alternativas que estão neste [site](http://alternativeto.net/software/jw-flv-player/) (Já usei alguns e são funcionais).

Comment: obrigada pela ajuda, ____1) mas eu usei o código acima, e nao funcionou! _____2) eu conheço o jwplayer e testei com ele também! ____ 3) se eu troco a extenssao do arquivo funciona!  ____ 4) poderia postar seu codigo?  obrigada!